# Couldn't find Service account Role on GCP for Cloud Natural Language API

Tags: google-cloud-platform, service-accounts, google-natural-language

I was setting up a GCP project for testing Google's Cloud Natural Language API. I'm just doing the resource manager role and I want to provide access to a developer for accessing this API via a service account. But, when I try to create a role for the service account for accessing the Cloud Natural Language API, I couldn't find any role related to that API. In the get started guide, they mentioned setting the 'Project owner' role for simplicity.

In my case, I require the service account to access only the Cloud Natural Language API. What should I do for my use case. If I missed that particular role or if the role has a different name, please guide me to that role too.

(I searched for ***Natural Language*** in the roles section and found nothing.) Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Ah many legacy Google Cloud API, only the activation of the API is required on the project. A Service Account, without any permission on the project, is able to perform request to the API.